# Ruby on Rails will not send request as JS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have a simple CRUD application that I used rails to scaffold and build. I'm new to rails and now I am trying to implement ajax with this application. I've searched dozens of tutorials and documentation that all says to add `local: false` to `forms_with` in order to set the `data-remote='true'` attribute on my form. I am able to do this successfully and when I inspect the form in the DOM I can see that `data-remote='true'` is on the form. Additionally I add `format.js` to the appropriate controller and a js.erb file in the views for the appropriate method. When the form is submitted the request is sent as HTML instead of Javascript and I get the following error regarding `format.js`: `ActionController::UnknownFormat`. Is there additional configuration I have to do or am I skipping a step? I'm totally stumped

Comment: What version of Ruby in Rails do you use?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: In my case, I have missed to install the packages. After the packages are installed in my system using yarn, JS format is working without any issues.

Comment: Posting the controller and view would help, without it, its very hard to say what's going on.  It's acting like it can't find your js file or the reference to the js file is not correct.